# Can a nontrivial spectrum smash to zero with $K$-theory? 

Tags: stable-homotopy, at.algebraic-topology

Let $E $ be a (possibly nonconnective) spectrum. Suppose $E \wedge K = 0$ (where $K$ is complex $K$-theory). Does it follow that $E = 0$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  Smashing a based space with a spectrum is equivalent to smashing
its suspension spectrum with that spectrum.  So it suffices to give a 
nontrivial space whose reduced $K$-homology is trivial.  A classical 
example due to Luke Hodgkin is $Coker J$.  See Hodgkin, Luke; Snaith, Victor.
The K-theory of some more well-known spaces. 
Illinois J. Math. 22 (1978), no. 2, 270–278.

Comment: Peter, you don't mean "sure". You mean "surely not".

Comment: Right you are Tom, I surely mean surely not.  But Akhil understood.

Comment: Tom, actually the original ``Sure'' was in answer to the original question.  And for that question the answer ``Sure'' is clearly right.

Answer (score 10):

Another type of example: Let $E$ be the mod $p$ homology spectrum. The integral homology groups of the periodic $K$-theory spectrum are rational vector spaces, i.e. the integral homology groups of the mod $p$ spectrum are zero.

Comment: Moreover, you can prove this without too much computation.  Both $K$ and $H/p$ are complex oriented, so a quite conceptual argument shows that the additive formal group law (associated to $H/p$) and the multiplicative one (associated to $K$) become isomorphic over `$\pi_*(K\wedge H/p)$`.  A simple algebraic argument now shows that `$\pi_*(K\wedge H/p)=0$`.

Comment: Neil, that's nice. The proof that I know consists of examining the effect of the Bott map $S^2\wedge BU\to BU$ on integral homology. This comes down to calculating the Chern class(es) of the generator of $\tilde K(S^{2n})$, which can be done using the Chern character.

Comment: @Neil: I know that argument works more generally. Would you mind posting it as a separate answer?